# Remove Files if the installer folder is Program Files

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I have Wix Installer for my 32-bit Application i.e. it always set up the files in Program Files(x86). SO when the user installs it on the 32-bit machine I want to remove some of the dlls from it.

I am not registering any values in Registry and don't want to that way. Is there any other way than this?

Comment: Remove them from your installer so they're not put there in the first place.

Comment: For this, I have to have a different installer for 64bit and 32 bit.

Comment: You can have files installed only on one platform and not the other.

Comment: Sorry. I was not knowing we can do that. Can you Share any link for example? Thank you :)

Comment: You can search here for examples. It's part of the effort you're supposed to put into solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need separate MSI files for 32-bit and 64-bit, assuming that you have 64-code that you want to install and run. 32-bit apps will install on 64-bit systems and run in 32-bit mode, but it appears that you have 64-bit Dlls.

This is a good outline of why you need two installs:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures/

For example there are different folder locations such as ProgramFilesFolder for 32-bit program files and ProgramFiles64Folder for 64-bit setups.

and this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367451(v=vs.85).aspx

points out that 32-bit packages can contain only 32-bit components, and 64-bit packages can contain 64-bit and some 32 bit components.

Comment: I knew that. I went through so many sites and found the same answer. There is no way to set up one installer for both the platforms. In my case, I can still avoid this (but ideally I Shouldn't do this, but still) as my dlls are 32 bit and my application always gets installed in Program Files(x86). It works on both the OS but for 32-bit OS I have to manually delete some of my dlls and it works just fine because I target it to Any CPU. Thank you so much for your help.